# How does server-side rendering work with a non-Node.js backend on Heroku?

Tags: python, node.js, reactjs, heroku, server-side-rendering

I have been developing a Python app that serves a React frontend with server-side rendering.

Locally, this has worked fine as I'm able to run two servers on separate ports to handle different parts of my application.  My Python backend receives the initial request and then sends an http request to my Node.js server which does my server-side rendering.  The result is then sent back to my Python backend which injects the server-rendered frontend into the HTML which is sent to the client.

However, Heroku limits applications to a single, dynamically generated port.  This limits me to only running one web server which means I'm no longer able to run my Node.js server to do my server-side rendering.  I have thought of some gimmicky ways to make this work, but I don't want to have to create an entirely new app on Heroku just to run the Node.js server I need.

I'm not sure how I can make this work with these limitations in place so I'm hoping I can learn some alternative ways to make this work on Heroku.  What are some viable workarounds to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create to separate apps on Heroku(even though you don't want to), as far as I know there's no other available options on Heroku.

I use Heroku for a SSR application running on two apps. One for frontend(react) and one for backend(nodejs). Works like a charm